# What is the "n" parameter in the JPEG spec's DQT segment?

Tags: jpeg, quantization

I'm in the process of writing a JPEG file decoder to learn about the workings of JPEG files. In working through [ITU-T81](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/itu-t81.pdf), which specifies JPEG, I ran into the following regarding the `DQT` segment for quantization tables:

[image: DQT syntax]

In many of JPEG's segments, there is an `n` parameter which you read from the segment, which then indicates how many iterations of the following item there are. However, in the DQT case, it just says "multiple", and its not defined how many multiples there are. One can possibly infer from `Lq`, but the way this multiple is defined is a bit of an anomaly compared to the other segments.

For anyone who is familiar with this specification, what is the right way to determine how many multiples, or `n`, of (`Pq`, `Tq`, `Q0`..`Q63`) there should be?

Answer (score 0):

Take the length field (LQ), subtract the length of the Pq/Tq field (one byte if I remember), and that is N.